# DataGridViewRow

Tags: datagridview

I am having a DataGridView in which user can add delete and insert rows manually.
Initialy DataGridView fetches data from the database and populate the grid.
I have to figure out all the rows that user manually added ( which are not fetched from the database)

Is there any flag to check if the Current row is newly added row while iterating the rows in the Datagridview ?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add another datacolumn and check the status of the column?

When the user manually adds a new row then update the datacolumn with a boolean value.

Comment: Is datacolumn has dirty flag property?
Can you please provide some code snippet, it will be much easeir for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Do what Phoenix said or save the newly created rows as soon as the user is done creating the row. Then you won't have to worry about it.